# Images not loading/ fly away buttons

Tags: html, css, image, flash, position

I made some changes to a website for someone and it works and looks perfectly when I open them in chrome, but as soon as I upload them on to the iPage server and look at them on the actual site everything is broken.
The index page is the only page that looks how it's suppose too. I've exhausted most of my resources and the person is furious. Anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: can you be more specific? what exactly doesnt look how its supposed to, and how exactly is it supposed to look like? which images are not loading, and what buttons fly where?

Comment: and all this works fine from your local computer? the issues start only after you upload it?

Comment: Yes sir, it works fine on my computer

Comment: start the website from your computer once again, open it in a web browser and press Ctrl+R to reload all resources and make sure that it still looks as its supposed to. if it does, then make a clean upload to iPage, completely delete your website from the server and upload a clean copy. sometimes this can be caused by the browser caching the css files and pictures, and even if you upload new ones under the same name - the browser will use the old ones until you instruct it to reload them.

Comment: oh i've just noticed you said you've cleared your cache. nevertheless, upload a clean copy first.

Comment: Thank you so so so so so much Banana! Can you tell me what was causing the issue, so I don't make a similar mistake in the future?

Comment: if the clean upload helped, then it could mean several things, either some of the old files were not replaced when you made the upload, or the server cached the website, or it did not rebuild it after you uploaded the new revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, wrap all the buttons inside a  container. Make the buttons width 25%, float them left and then position the container, as you haven't provided any code i'll provide an example for you. This should solve the problem.

Inside the container where the buttons are, create a new div and call it button container and wrap it around buttons.

```
    <div id ="button_container">
//button tags go here
    </div>
```

For CSS assign the width and height to the button container and for the buttons including the css you have now.

```
#button_container {width:25%; height:30px;} //example dimensions
#button1, #button2, #button3, #button4 {width:25%; height:100%; float:left;}
```

make sure the container has a margin so that is above the other content. you can also make the container 100% width to match the width of it's parent.